# Writing large arrays to memory x86 assembly - segfaults using stack space

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, stack-memory, ulimit

I'm trying to write an array to the stack in x86 assembly using the AT&T (GAS) syntax. I have ran into an issue whereby I can write ~8.37 million entries to the stack, and then I get a `Segmentation fault` if I try to write any more. I don't know why this is, here's the code I'm using:

```
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    mov $8378658, %rdx
writeDataLoop:
    sub %rdx, %rbp
    movb $0b1, (%rbp)

    add %rdx, %rbp

    sub $1, %rdx
    cmp $0, %rdx
    jg writeDataLoop
```

Another odd thing that I've found is that the limit at which I can write data up to changes very slightly with each run (it's roughly at 8378658, which is also nothing significant in hex (0x7fd922). Can anyone tell me how to write more data to the stack, and also potentially explain what this arbitrary stack write limit is? Thanks.

Comment: Default stack size is 8MB. See `ulimit -a`. Don't put big things onto the stack.

Comment: Ah yes I see this now thanks, what do you suggest I do to store large amounts of data then?

Comment: @OliverF Either use dynamic memory allocation (e.g. through `malloc`) or reserve space in the `.bss` section with the `.space` directive.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: It may sound silly, but can you tell me how to access individual bytes in the .space directive?

Comment: Use a label and an offset. E.g. `buffer: .space 1024` then reference using `buffer+10` or `buffer(%rsi)` or similar.

Comment: @OliverF Same as with any other memory.  `.space` just reserves the given number of bytes.  Stick a label in front so you know where the space was reserved, then use that label to refer to the memory location.  If this is confusing to you I can go ahead and write an answer with an example.

Comment: Ah thanks to both of you, I knew that a label was required, I was just a little unsure of the syntax required for accessing the data at the location. I now know how, from @Jester s clarification.

Comment: @OliverF Cool!  Now write up what you learned as an answer and post it under your question.  This way people know that your question has been resolved and future people with the same question will see how you resolved it.

Comment: Will do! Thanks a lot.

Comment: One reason why the stack limit exists is so that infinite recursion bugs cause the program to crash before it uses up all the system's memory.  The limit is meant to be big enough that a "reasonable" program is unlikely to run out, but small enough that infinite recursion fails faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start off with, the default stack size is 8MB, this is the stack limit I was reaching. This can be found with the `ulimit -a` command. However, one **should not** use the stack for large amounts of data (usually arrays). Instead, the `.space` directive should be used, which, using AT&T syntax, takes the amount of data to store in bytes: `.space <buffersize>`. This can be labelled, for example:

`buffer: .space 1024`

This allocates 1024 bytes of storage to the label `buffer`. This label should be in the `.bss` section of your program, allowing for read and write access.

Finally, to access this data (read or write), one can use `buffer(%rax)`, where `rax` is the offset.

Edit:
Using the `.bss` section is more efficient file-size wise than using the `.data` section, you just have to manually initialize the array.

Comment: Not sure if `.data` section is correct. I would expect the `.bss` section for read/write data.

Comment: @tum_ `.bss` is designed for blocks of space initialized with zeroes and without saving the initial values in the binary. Yes this is what would make sense here if it's an array without intial values, but from a read-write/readonly perspective `.data` is fine too (`.rdata` would not be), it's for initialized read/write data.

Comment: I only used the `.data` section because I wanted to initialize every element to a default value. Also, I see from reading around online that `malloc` does seem far easier to use, but for now I will keep my answer as it is, as I like not using any C functions in my code (it's only ~200 lines).

Comment: Just to add to this: A more flexible approach (and what's happening by default in most programs nowadays) is to allocate memory dynamically using the `malloc` function (or equivalent) to allocate memory on the heap (or a step deeper: the relevant platform-specific system API for allocating a raw block of memory) and only saving the _pointer_ to the newly allocated memory on the stack or in a global variable.

Comment: @OliverF Note that even if you want to have a default value, it might be a good idea to manually do the initialisation.  If you put `.space 8*1024*1024, 1` into `.data`, that means, you're going to have an 8 MB binary.  A lot of disk space is saved by placing the array into `.bss` and then initialising it yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the improvement - I'll test and then update my answer if necessary.

Comment: Using `malloc` allows for a dynamic size, which is a great advantage in most programming as one doesn't have to pick a maximum size (though simply not required in some).  `malloc` requires error handling for the case the request is too large, whereas `.bss` space doesn't since the program won't load if it can't guarantee the initial memory requirements.  (But a fixed size space needs its own limit handling.)  `malloc` requires initializing the memory, but `.bss` is automatically zeroed.  `calloc` can be used instead of zeroing, when appropriate.